# Display number of rows if they are placed in date/time range

Tags: spotfire

I have a table with info about different tasks with following structure

```
id    start_time             finish_time
1     20.12.2018 16:12:06    20.12.2018 16:18:52
2     20.12.2018 16:15:03    20.12.2018 16:22:48
3     20.12.2018 16:18:04    20.12.2018 16:25:23
```

I would like to create bar chart with visualization about how many tasks are processed in each moment of time: binned datetime by minutes on X-axis and Count for rows on Y-axis.
As was planned before, the first row from example table should be counted in each bar in range from 16:12 to 16:18. But I only was able to make spotfire count values on the column that was binned on X-axis (finish_time)

So there is two questions

1. How to make spotfire take into account values wihin range from start_time and finish_time?
2. Is it possible to bin X-axis by date time without binding formula to a column? For example the whole time range for the last year?

Comment: For #1, the only thing that comes to mind is transforming your data to have each id repeated for each minute that the time interval spans. For example, you'd have id == 1 on 7 different records. You could probably handle this transformation in TERR, although I know that dates can be tricky with it.